# Client Socket Port is different between Server Socket port

Tags: java, sockets

I've wrote simple client (using SocketChannel):

```
 User friend = database.getUserByName("jonh");
 SocketChannel friendSkt = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(friend.getHost()), friend.getPort()));
 System.out.println("Local: " + friendSkt.socket().getLocalSocketAddress()
                    + " |Remote: "+ friendSkt.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
```

and server (using simple Socket):

```
 ServerSocket skt = new ServerSocket(0);

 Socket server = skt.accept();
 InputStream x = server.getInputStream();
 System.out.println("Local: " + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + " |Remote: "+ server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
```

Even if connect returns no exception and client write on socket (simple getOutputStream.write(...)), server not read and returns -1. So I've printed the address of each socket and found this:

CLIENT: `Local: /192.168.0.2:58981 |Remote: /192.168.0.2:58968`

SERVER: `Local: /192.168.0.2:58968 |Remote: /192.168.0.2:58980`

It is normal that client local port is server remote port+1 instead to being the same value?

Comment: No, this is not normal.  On the server side, this suggests that another client has connected to your server, and you are printing that client's info instead of your client's info. This would also be consistent with your symptom that your read fails, if that other client is not writing anything to the server.  Try calling `accept()` in a loop and see how many clients are actually connecting to your `ServerSocket` port.

Comment: You are binding your `ServerSocket` to port 0, so it will listen on a random available port, and maybe someone else's client app is expecting to connect to the port that you *happen* to be listening on at that moment.